# trying to name items in a structure using a for loop

Tags: c, struct

for part of my program I need to make items in a structure. however the ammount of items created depends on an input

I am trying to give each item a unique name after the value of the count in the for loop

e.g. if the input is 4 I would like four items being named 1,2,3,4

my code so far:

structure:

```
struct points{
 int xcoord;//x coordinate of point
 int ycoord;//y cooridnate of point
 int nextState;
};
```

main code:

```
scanf("%i",&turns);
                       
int count;
for(count=0; count<turns; ++count)
 {
  struct points &count; //the structure tag is points 
 }
```

however this causes this error

```
 error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘&’ token
  struct points &count;
```

Comment: Why do you need structure? Won't normal array work?

Comment: `count>turns` looks like a bug.

Comment: what did you expect with the '&' in `struct points &count;` ? probably you want without

Comment: You need an array, not a structure.

Comment: You need an array of the structure.

Comment: Also `xcoord` is not in your posted code. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe desired behavior.

Comment: im trying to use a structure as opposed to an array as it will make it easier to remove items in the rest of the code, as the structurs also contain 3 variables i think ity would be easier to manage as a structure then as 3 arrays

Comment: @JDSBerg give the definition of your structure. Let remarks the errors produced by the compiler cannot be for the code you give us. `give each item a unique name` what do you mean ? Please edit your question, currently it is impossible to understand/answer you

Comment: @bruno I added the definition of the structure to the question. by "give each item a unique name" I meant that the item would be named after the value inside the variable as opposed to the name of the variable so that this code would be able to make multiplr items not just one named count

Comment: You should use a hash table which should have string keys. And good luck doing that in C.

Comment: @JDSBerg the error from the compiler you give are about `struct alive &i;`and `&i.xcoord = 4;` which are not in your 'main' code you give us. Anyway, again, what do you expect using '&' as you do ... out of a syntax error ? The name of the field of a struct / union are not dynamic but statically known when you compile ... this is why there are arrays where the index and may be the size can be dynamic and only known during the execution

Comment: you want something like that : `if ((scanf("%i",&turns) != 1) || (turns < 1)) { ...error bad value... } else { struct points counts[turns]; ...use of points[0] up to points[turns-1];... }`

Comment: @bruno my bad I was using errors from an earlier version ive added the correct error, the reason I added the & was more of a guess on hown to name the item as I assumed that by doing that the name of the item would be the value stored in count as opposed to the word "count" e.g. in the first loop the value of count would be 0 and therefore the name of the item would be zero

Comment: @JDSBerg ok, anyway that changes nothing about what I said about the struct/union fields nor the fact you want an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Several defects in your code:

1. As pointed out in the comment on the question, there's no meaning of using:

   ```
   for (count = 0; count > turns; count++)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   You're initializing the `count` as zero and then comparing whether the `turns` is lesser than `0` or not, if so, then increment count, which is an error.
2. This line:

   ```
   struct points &count;
   ```

   doesn't makes any sense either & clearly a syntax error.

---

### The corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100

typedef struct {
    int cX;
    int cY;
} point;

int main(void) {
    // Declaring 100 p's
    point p[MAX];
    
    // Get user input...

    for (int i = 0; i < turns; i++) {
        printf("Enter cX[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &p[i].cX);

        printf("Enter cY[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &p[i].cY);
    }

    // Next statements to work with those structs...
}
```

**Note:** If you're using C99, there's one advantage of it, the VLAs (Variable Length Array) is supported. So, you can ask the user for `turns` & then declare the struct:

```
scanf("%d", &turns);
point p[turns];
```